# Java, How to delete an undeletable file/folder in Windows

Tags: java

I am new to Java programming language. And would like to do a small app to learn on and get a head start into java.
I use an app called unlocker from emptyloop dot com. But its got adware, etc. So I just wanted to learn how to write my own app for myself to delete undeletable file or folder in windows. 
Can anyone help me out, or know where I can find an example, I tried googling, but had no luck.

Comment: Stackoverflow is full of examples about how to work with files. Please read first some infos, than try something. And in the case you have problems after that all, you can ask a more specific question

Comment: This is defnitely not a good start for learning how to program. Imagine: just a small mistake and you delete essential folders?!

Comment: I haven't come across an undeletable file so far. At least none survived the 10 minute mark in the microwave. Maybe you should go to eleven? If you do not have sufficient rights to delete a file, contact your administrator, he does.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess Java wouldn't be the right choice for that since it's a platform independent framework. And 'unlocking' files is very platform dependent in my opinion
But maybe you take a look at [ForceDel](http://sourceforge.net/projects/forcedel/). It's open source software and claims to do what you are looking for.

> ForceDel uses some exciting new APIs introduced with Microsoft Windows Vista to determine which processes have a specified file in use. With this information, ForceDel is able to close the file in the remote process address space and then delete the file.
>   
> Starting with version 1.2, ForceDel can also delete files on Windows XP.